# Is there a reasonable way of debugging yaml-cpp

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, yaml-cpp

Is there a way for visualising YAML::Node in a comprehensible way in VS, such we can see what its type is, what are first and second, to make it short, to know what is going on at some debugging step?

Here is what i see:

[image]

Nathaniel

Comment: @ Nathaniel Perez, any update? What about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the type of the variable, in debugging tool, we often add it to the debug window like the watch windows, and then visit the type and the detailed value of it. Just click the drop down lists like the following screen shot(just a sample).

[image]

But if you want to see it in short, no good suggestions unless you want to write custom native extension.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx